# Python: pattern matching for a string

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to check a file line by line for any_string=any_string. It must be that format, no spaces or anything else. The line must contain a string then a "=" and then another string and nothing else. Could someone help me with the syntax in python to find this please? =]

```
pattern='*\S\=\S*'
```

I have this, but im pretty sure its wrong haha.

Comment: How do you intend to use that pattern?

Comment: Also, I think this is more of a regex question than a Python question. Just saying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you are looking for lines with the same value on both `=` sides. If so then use:

```
the_same_re = re.compile(r'^(\S+)=(\1)$')
```

if values can differ then use

```
the_same_re = re.compile(r'^(\S+)=(\S+)$')
```

In this regexpes:

- `^` is the beginning of line
- `$` is the end of line
- `\S+` is one or more non space character
- `\1` is first group

`r` before regex string means "raw" string so you need not escape backslashes in string.

Comment: thanks! defining what each expression does also helped a lot =]

Comment: the code you gave me works, but how do i match exactly one '='?
    (r'^(\S+)={1}(\S+)$')
doesnt seem to work

Comment: Try: `r'^([^=\s]+)=([^=\s]+)$')`, in `[` brackets `^` excludes chars and in this example it excludes `=` and whitespaces (`\s`)

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = r'\S+=\S+'
```

If you want to be able to grab the left and right-hand sides, you could add capture groups:

```
pattern = r'(\S+)=(\S+)'
```

If you don't want to allow multiple equals signs in the line (which would do weird things), you could use this:

```
pattern = r'[^\s=]+=[^\s=]+'
```

Comment: thanks, ya i would probably need to capture it for later use soo..
    pattern = r'([^\s=])+=(^\s=]+)'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the tasks you want make use this pattern. Maybe you want parse configuration file.
If it is true you may use module ConfigParser.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to find `anystring=anystring` and nothing else. Then no need regex.

```
>>> s="anystring=anystring"
>>> sp=s.split("=")
>>> if len(sp)==2:
...   print "ok"
...
ok
```

Comment: That will find any line with one "=" in it.  Probably need to check that neither of the parts are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 2.5 I prefer this to split. If you don't like spaces, just check.

```
left, _, right = any_string.partition("=")
if right and " " not in any_string:
    # proceed
```

Also it never hurts to learn regular expressions.